# How to configure IMAP for Gmail

Tags: gmail, imap

I have IMAP on and I had it working before. Now I reinstalled my OS and I want to enable Outlook in Windows 7 with Gmail but it's not authenticating.

[image]

I have 2-way authentication turned on. Should this be working or is it impossible because I have 2-way authentication on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to generate an application-specific password from [your Google Account Settings](https://accounts.google.com/b/0/IssuedAuthSubTokens?hl=en_GB#accesscodes). Once done, that application specific password must be provided in Outlook, instead of your regular password.